# How to get all values of a field pack channel field

Tags: field-pack, channel-fields

I've a `Channel Field`, I create a `field-pack drop-down list` that works great on the Article page back-end.

Now I need to get all values of that list and output it into the article temple if i do `{cuisine:label}` it will give me the selected value as set on the back-end when the article was created. But I need all values not only the selected one.

How can I get the full list of that particular channel field - drop down to output it into a template?

The rational is that in the front-end I need to recreate that list and then use those values for search queries. Hence I need value:label pairs so i dont have to replicate the data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't known your complete use case, but a drop down isn't really the right field type to go with, I suspect. You can't output it as you want, and would have to use some front-end jQuery-izing to take the field and convert it into a list.

I would use the Checkboxes field. Ref:

http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/fieldpack/fieldtypes/checkboxes/tags.html#ol-and-ul-tags

That will allow you to output your values as a list. But as a side note... ever hear of fusion cuisine? :p you might want to allow multiple selections for that field on a content level, because half the world does fusion.

Comment: What I am trying to do is create a list of all those `label:values` to use in a sort by/search box for the front-end user. I don't want to have to repeat that list-data manually